# Spring data specification is not working as expected with pageable

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are working with Spring Data specification for creating dynamic queries and have Pagination. Getting the following error in some cases where we change the values of Pageable size and page.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not locate TableGroup - com.example.ganymede.report.data.models.ReportsEntity(357331951142118)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:320)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:229)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
        at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy157.findAll(Unknown Source)
    ......
```

**Specification:**

```
final String isDeleted = ReportsEntity.Fields.isDeleted;
final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
final Specification<T> tSpecification =
        (root, cq, builder) -> {
                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(isDeleted), Boolean.FALSE));

                return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
```

**Pageable:**

```
PageRequest.of(page.getNumber() - 1, page.getSize(), Sort.by(direction, sortAttribute));
```

**Repository:**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface ReportsRepository extends JpaRepository<ReportsEntity, Long>,
                JpaSpecificationExecutor<ReportsEntity> {

    Page<UserReportsEntity> findAll(Specification spec, Pageable pageable);                

}
```

The current change is working as expected in a few cases but failing in other cases.

**Working case:** Suppose the total rows in the `reports` table are 15 and if we make the `Pageable` request. Here, the `page.number * page.size` is around the total number of rows in the database table.

```
 {attribute: "createdAt", direction: DESC}

 "page": {
    "number": 1,
    "size": 16
  }

//or
"page": {
    "number": 2,
    "size": 8
  }

//or
"page": {
    "number": 3,
    "size": 6
  }
```

**Failed case:**

```
"page": {
    "number": 3,
    "size": 8
  }

//or
"page": {
    "number": 1,
    "size": 8
  }

//or
"page": {
    "number": 2,
    "size": 15
  }
```

We are currently running Spring boot v3.1.1 with Hibernate v6.2.5.Final and CockroachDB v22.1

is the above behavior of Specification and pageable expected? Did we miss some configuration or any other changes?